# Django Rest Framework combine 2 queries

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

i have machine model, supposing machine has different status such as produce, maintain, pending and etc. I would like to build an api to response the latest machine status by calling: http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/machinestatus/?machines=2,7
this endpoint should response the status for machine ID 2 and 7, I've tried many ways but still cannot make it work, please help

model:

```
class MachineStatus(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=False, null=False)
    machine = models.ForeignKey(
        Machine, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=False, null=False)
    upt_time = models.DateTimeField(blank=False, null=False)
    status = models.CharField(
        max_length=1, choices=JOB, blank=False, null=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.machine} {self.upt_time} {self.status}"

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "MachineStatus"
```

serializer:

```
class MachineStatusSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    upt_time = serializers.DateTimeField(read_only=True)
    status = serializers.CharField(read_only=True)
    user = serializers.SlugRelatedField(read_only=True, slug_field='username')
    machine = serializers.SlugRelatedField(
        read_only=True, slug_field='name')

    class Meta:
        model = MachineStatus
        fields = '__all__'
```

view:

```
class MachineStatusView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    ''' Machine Status View '''
    queryset = MachineStatus.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MachineStatusSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = MachineStatus.objects.all()
        machines = self.request.query_params.get('machines')
        if machines:
            machines = machines.split(',')
            for i in machines:
                queryset = MachineStatus.objects.all()
                queryset = queryset.filter(machine=i).order_by('-upt_time')[:1]
                \\ question: how to combine queries' result?

        return queryset
```

each "i" would call queryset with result of corresponding latest machine status, but the problem is how to combine these queryset in the for loop?  thanks alot

or is there any better other way to achieve this?
I've tried machine__in = machine without for loop but since i'm not using progresql, i cannot use distinct("machine").

appreciate for the help

Answer (score 2):

you can use where in

```py
# first make the distinct by converting it to a set
machine_ids = list(set(self.request.query_params.get('machines')))
queryset = MachineStatus.objects.filter(machine_id__in = machine_ids).order_by('-upt_time')[:1]
```

Answer (score 0):

My proposal would be to make a sql view which contain id, machine_id , last_status.
Then create a model and connect it to this sql view and make a link between machines and the last machines state .